# Powershell 2.0 net use filter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

All,

I need to do a awk '{print $2} and move the result to a variable in powershell 2.0. The output i generate is from the line:
`net use | select-string -pattern public`
The drive letter that comes out of the above filter is what i need in a variable.

Thanks in advance.
OSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$var = @(net use) -match 'public' -replace '^\w+\s+([A-Z]:).+','$1'
```

That will handle single or multiple instance of shares that match 'public', and include the colon in the captured data.
Move that right paren back one place to trim the colon out of the results if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks for that mj. Mind letting me know where to know a bit more about these regexs pls.

Comment: Powershell has some very good help built in. Runt through get-help about_regular_expressions.  That should answer a bunch of questions, and probably raise a few more :).